# C# paint program saving bitmap to different formats

Tags: image, bitmap, format, paint, savefiledialog

I am working on a program that should be basically a paint program but with the possibility to save the drawn image to like 5 formats or so. So I figured out that in order to save it I need to draw on bitmap. But when I try to save the image, in the drop down menu I have only one option and it shows the two formats next to each other, and it always saves it as .bmp.  http://s8.postimg.org/97wj3x2v9/Bez_n_zvu.jpg

I am using a save file dialog. How can I save it to more formats? For example .jpg, .png and others?

This is the code for saving i curently have.

```
    {
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.jpg";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bitmapa.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter is divided to two parts: `description` of the filter and the filter `pattern`.
For each format you need a "filter"(a new description and pattern). So for `.bmp, .jpg and .png`:

```
"Bmp Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp    |Jpeg Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg     |Png Files (*.png)|*.png";
    description     pattern     description      pattern       description    pattern
```

And if you want a general filter for all three formats:

```
"Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.png)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png|Bmp Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|Jpeg Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Png Files (*.png)|*.png";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now and I also used System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat to change the format of the saved file. :)